# Unexpected identifier on function creation - js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

When creating a function in js, as soon as I create the function, it gives me the error stated in the title. It also says ';' expected, however, I cannot find the issue. The function is "created()" and I've intentionally left it blank because it gives the error as soon as I have it like that.

Here is the code:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        errors: [],
        name: null,
        age: null
    },
    methods:{
        checkForm: function (e) {
            if (this.name && this.age) {
                console.log(this.name);
                return true;
            }
            

            console.log(this.name);

            async created() {

            }

            this.errors = [];

            if (!this.name) {
                this.errors.push('Name required.');
            }
            if (!this.age) {
                this.errors.push('Age required.');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What does `async created() {}` do? It is invalid syntax

Comment: `async created() { }` -> `async function created() { }` or delete it altogether.

Comment: I sorted it out. Here is my new error in the browser:

from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Thats not valid. `created()` is a own hook of vue and should be outside of `methods`.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    errors: [],
    name: null,
    age: null
  },
  methods: {
    checkForm: function(e) {
      if (this.name && this.age) {
        console.log(this.name);
        return true;
      }

      console.log(this.name);

      this.errors = [];

      if (!this.name) {
        this.errors.push("Name required.");
      }
      if (!this.age) {
        this.errors.push("Age required.");
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  async created() {
    console.log("instance created");
  }
});
```

Comment: there are more like `beforeCreate`, `mounted` etc. Here take a look https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram @NiklasE.